# A geometric proof of Picard's little theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm preparing a presentation where I'd like to present a proof of Picard's little theorem using hyperbolic geometry. Picard's little theorem states that the range of an entire function can omit *at most $1$ point*.

I can see that we can write $U:=\mathbb{C}P^1\setminus\{\infty,0,1\}$ as a hyperbolic manifold, and as a quotient of $\mathbb{D}$ through the [Farey tesselation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence). I would like to say therefore that any conformal map $:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow U$ would factor conformally through $\mathbb{D}$.

I can see that it should factor through the covering map, but can I even say that the covering map is conformal?

I know that *Ahlfors' Lemma* helps, but all the statements I've obtained of said lemma hold for *Hermite metrics*. Can I say that the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{C}P^1\setminus\{\infty,0,1\}$ is Hermite?

Comment: Of course to both. Hermitian metrics are the analog on complex manifolds of Riemannian metrics on real manifolds; any metric $f(z)|dz|^2$ on a $1$-dimensional complex manifold (for $f>0$) is a hermitian metric. And covering maps are local biholomorphisms, hence conformal, yes.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. +1 for pointing out that '*Hermitian metrics are the analog on complex manifolds of Riemannian metrics on real manifolds*'.